# Detecting kwarg override in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to detect whether a keyword arg was passed in explicitly, without using `**kwargs`.

Here is an example:

```
def foo(first, second=None):
    pass
```

If, in this function, I find that `second` contains `None`, is there a way to know whether that `None` was from the default, or was passed in explicitly? Basically, I have an optional argument that could conceivably be any value or type. So I either need some sort of "unique" default such that the user would never intentionally pass in that default, or I need a way to detect whether the argument was actually passed in explicitly.

I expect I could discover it by inspecting the stack, but I feel like that's overkill.

I also know I could do it this way:

```
def foo(first, **kwargs):
    if 'second' in kwargs:
        # Overridden!
        pass
```

But I would prefer not to accept `**kwargs`, as it makes my function signature less useful and can hide errors.

Comment: Short of using `**kwargs` which is not horrible, then use a *sentinel* value... eg `sentinel = object()` then check `if second is not sentinel`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always create a unique object and use it as the default:

```
_default = object()

def foo(first, second=_default):
    if second is not _default:
        # Overridden!
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

[NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27259410/240490) is exactly right: use a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) that isn't `None`. Any old [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object will do, much of the time.

There is one downside to `_default = object()` though: `_default` does not share `None`'s convenient property of being logically equal to `False` in conditionals. That is, `None` is "falsey," but `_default` is "truthy." More formally, `bool(None) == False` yet `bool(_default) == True`.

It'd be great if you could create new `NoneType` instances to be like `None`, but not quite `None`. But `NoneType` cannot be further instantiated. You can create a similar class, though. So:

```
import sys

_PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3

class NullType(object):

    """
    A 'null' type different from, but parallel to, None. Core function
    is representing emptyness in a way that doesn't overload None.
    This helps create designated identifiers with specific meanings
    such as Passthrough, Prohibited, and Undefined.

    Instantiate to create desired null singletons. While they are
    singletons, depends on usage convention rather than strict
    enforcement to maintain their singleton-ness. This is a problem
    roughly 0% of the time.
    """

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.name is not None:
            return self.name
        else:
            return 'NullType(id: {0})'.format(id(self))

    if _PY3:
        def __bool__(self):
            """I am always False."""
            return False
    else:  # PY2
        def __nonzero__(self):
            """I am always False."""
            return False
```

Drop that code in `nulltype.py` and then:

```
from nulltype import NullType
_default = NullType('_default')

def foo(first, second=_default):
    if second is not _default:
        # Overridden!
        pass
```

But you can also do:

```
    if second:
        ...
```

(in some contexts) because `second`'s truth value is equivalent to `None`'s. If you used the simpler `_default = object()` sentinel, you could not do that, because `bool(object()) == True`.

Now `_default` is unique, prints nicely when it needs to be printed, and is always equivalent to `False`. It's your own private `None`.

Comment: I like it! I'm going to mark NPE's answer as the real answer, but this was very useful, thanks!

Comment: His definitely has the beauty of simplicity and built-in-ness.